# PHP Tabela cor fundo

Tags: php, tabela-html

```
$aux = mysql_num_rows($sql2);

 $html = '';
 $html .= '<table border="1">';
 $html .= '<tr>';
 $html .= '<td colspan="3"><b><Center>'.$row[0].' </center></b></td></tr>';

 $html .= '<tr><td align="center"><b>Instalador</b></td>';
 $html .= '<td bgcolor="#A9A9A9" align="center"><b>Morada</b></td>';
 $html .= '<td align="center"><b>Email</b></td>'

 </tr>';


 for($i=1; $i<=$aux; $i ++){
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
 from Tabela WHERE id = $id = ".$i) or die(mysql_error());
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
 $html .= '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td>
 <td>'.$row[1].'</td>

 <td>'.$row[2].'</td>

 <td>'.$row[3].'</td>


 </tr>';


 }
 $html .= '</table>';
```

Estou com um problema em colocar cor de fundo nestas duas linhas:

```
 $html .= '<td bgcolor="#A9A9A9" align="center"><b>Morada</b></td>';
```

Aqui neste gostava de colocar uma regra pois vai receber datas. Se a data ja estiver sido passada o retangulo fica a vermelho.

```
 <td>'.$row[2].'</td>
```

Comment: Não percebi qual é que é a dúvida.

Comment: A sintaxe do seu código está errada...

Comment: Errada porque? Estes dados serão exportados para o Excel

Comment: Refaça a pergunta quando possível pois é complicado termos que ficar adivinhando o que você quis dizer. Você cita que está com "um problema em colocar cor de fundo nestas duas linhas" e na linha seguinte coloca o código onde insere a tag de uma **coluna** numa variável PHP. Onde estão as duas linhas? <td> é diferente de linha.

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que sua `$row[2]` seja uma data no formato `07/08/2014`

```
if( time() > strtotime( $row[2] ) )
    ...
```

---

. Recomendo o uso de PDO
. Ao contrário do que se pensa, `tables` não devem ser abolidas. Tabelas debem montar `TABELAS`. `Tableless` não significa não usar tabelas, mas sim, usa-las para seu propósito.

---

Aplicando no seu código:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$aux; $i ++)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from Tabela WHERE id = $id = ".$i) or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $style = null;

    if( time() > strtotime( $row[2] ) )
    $style = 'class = "data_vencida"';

    $html .= '<tr><td>' . $row[0] . '</td>
    <td>' . $row[1].'</td>
    <td ' . $style . '>' . $row[2] . '</td>
    <td>' . $row[3] . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

```
<style>
.data_vencida{background:#FF0000}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilize CSS ao invés do atributo **bgcolor**. No HTML 5 esse atributo não é mais suportado para `<td>`, `<tr>`, e `<table>` conforme informado no site da própria W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_bgcolor.asp).

> Compatibility Notes: The bgcolor attribute of  is not supported in
>   HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Para o seu caso o código poderia ficar da seguinte maneira:

```
$html .= '<td style="background-color: #A9A9A9" align="center"><b>Morada</b></td>';
```

Answer (score -1):

acho que você poderia deixar isso mais organizado, pensar em PDO e bootstrap, tentei salvar teu script, mais acho q ainda sim vai precisar de ajustes pra se enquadrar na tua necessidade.

```
<?php
/* ok, mais acho que talvez um pdo fosse mais seguro. */
$aux = mysql_num_rows($sql2);

/* acho q se tu fizer o select antes de formar a tabela fica mais simples
 * com pdo tu poderia inclusive utilizar um try catch nas consultas, mais enfim...
 * define a consulta antes, loop de consultas é deselegante, 
 * fica mal para o programador apresentar algo deste tipo a um cliente,
 * ou até pra um cachorro...
 */

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from TABELA WHERE id in(select id from TABELA where ...)") or die(mysql_error());

?>

<!-- mais uma dica, pesquisa sobre bootstrap,
    vale a pena por varios motivos, como acessibilidade, 
    padrão e profissionalismo -->

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <b><Center>???</center></b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <b>Instalador</b>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#A9A9A9" align="center">
            <b>Morada</b>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <b>Email</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print $row["nome"]; //passa o nome da coluna da sua tabela?></td>
        <td <?php if (!empty($row["data"])) { ?>style="background-color:#fff;"<?php } ?> ><?php print $row["data"]; //passa o nome da coluna da sua tabela ?></td>
        <td><?php print $row["blablabla"]; //passa o nome da coluna da sua tabela ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```